# RankMath Does not Save Focus Keyword

Tags: wordpress

trying to save my focus keyword and it not work after update.
I also disabled all plugins, but it still didn't help.

rankmath seo not saving anything
in console have these error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM6A5.png)
and nothing save in post after update.
Can anyone tell me why i am getting this error.